# Don't Log A Specific Sidekiq Job In Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sidekiq

I have a sidekiq job in rails and i dont want that job to write log in bundle exec sidekiq. How do i do that?

I am getting logs using this command "sudo tail -n 1000 /var/log/syslog | grep sidekiq". My job returns last 1000 sidekiq logs (1000 lines, each job approximately has 4 lines: start, enqueued with arguments (this part shows the data job taken), performed, done) and when i called this job many times, this causes to grow response larger and larger, because this job's log data has last 1000 sidekiq log. If i called it 5 times that means last jobs data will be massive(almost 16000).

I tried to use logfilterer which chatgpt suggested to me. i created logfilterer in lib file and created new logger set this log's loglevel to error level in /initializers/sidekiq.rb but that didn't work for me or i couldn't do it properly.
I tried to get 1000 logs and remove each line which includes that job's name but somehow data still getting larger.

Answer (score 0):

You can redirect the stdout and stderr to dev/null:

```
bundle exec sidekiq > /dev/null 2>&1
```

Or disable logging in the Sidekiq initializer:

```
Sidekiq.configure_server do |config|
  config.logger = Logger.new("/dev/null")
end
```

That said, your question is not clear, becuase you're grepping specifically for "sidekiq" word. You could use `grep -v "sidekiq"` to filter the lines, containing "sidekiq", because generally, it is not a good practice to disable logging.

Disabling logging for a specifical job seems not to be implemented. To minimize the logging, you can set, though, the log level in a job to `:fatal`:

```
sidekiq_options log_level: :warn
```

Comment: thanks for your answer but it is not i want to do. I just want to prevent a job's logging, not all jobs.

Comment: Preventing a specific job's logging seems not to be implemented. I have update my answer to also show how to set a job's log level.